# Logged out of Twitter whenever I restart the browser even with ‘Remember me’ option

Tags: twitter, login

Is anyone else experiencing the same problem? I have it with both Opera 11 and Safari 5 on the two separate Macs.

I have reset cookies and done the usual troubleshooting.

I have the always-use-HTTPS option enabled in my Twitter account, if that could be relevant.

Comment: Do you allow third party cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter "remembers" you by storing a cookie in your browser.  Check to make sure you are not clearing cookies frequently and that you don't have any settings in Opera/Safari that deletes cookies when you close the browser.

Comment: I do not have a browser setting that says to delete cookies when I end the browser session. My Safari is vanilla. No customization including settings.

Answer (score 0):

Consider contacting [@support](http://twitter.com/support) if this is still a problem. If you are on vanilla Safari then nothing via the browser should be affecting it.

[image: Cookies for Twitter]

If you don't have the above when checking settings on re-opening Safari then you *do not* have cookies stored for Twitter.